# No ad in AdMob example (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service, android-sdk-tools

I downloaded an ad example: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/start
but when I run it on a device it shows no ad (online mode of the project).
In logs it tells that it is failed to load ad.

Here are some lines from log:

```
02-29 05:18:26.923 33-33/? E/Zygote: setreuid() failed. errno: 2
02-29 05:18:27.802 33-33/? W/MediaProfiles: could not find media config xml file
02-29 05:19:10.883 78-84/? W/zipro: Unable to open zip '/data/local/bootanimation.zip': No such file or directory
02-29 05:19:10.905 78-84/? W/zipro: Unable to open zip '/system/media/bootanimation.zip': No such file or directory
02-29 05:19:25.492 67-79/system_process W/PackageManager: Package com.example.android.apis desires unavailable shared library com.example.will.never.exist; ignoring!
02-29 05:19:25.662 67-79/system_process W/PackageManager: Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.mail in package com.android.contacts
02-29 05:20:51.480 336-336/com.google.samples.quickstart.admobexample W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3
```